# Override htaccess in joomla

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I need to rewrite a url for specific component in joomla so that actual component name is not visible in url .

E.g index.php?option=com_mycomponent

I need to replace com_mycomponent to xyz

Also I installed joomsef extension but it does not work fine with language filter plugin in joomla.

So I need to rewrite a  url for specific component using htaccess

So please suggest me appropriate solution asap

Comment: Some components in Joomla! need input from your URL to function properly; if there is POST data in the URL then the component might not work after being rewritten. Can you name which component or extension you are trying to mask?

Comment: I have created a custom component com_jrestaurantreservation and I need to rewrite urls for that extension to chaletreservation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Simple Custom Router" extension may be able to help you:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/21251

Hopefully this is ASAP enough for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a basic .htaccess rewrite? Shouldn't be too tough with basic rewrite engine:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^my_component_pretty_url$    ?option=com_mycomponent    [NC,L]
```

If anyone has better rewrite rules, please add...mine are super basic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^chaletreservation$ index.php?option=com_jrestaurantreservation        [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^chaletreservation(.+)$ index.php?option=com_jrestaurantreservation&$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then simply use where ever you need this component urls `index.php?option=com_jrestaurantreservation` like below,

```
www.yourdomain.com/chaletreservation
```

Hope its works..